# (Algorithm) find nodes having single path to reach from one node to other

Tags: java, algorithm

I wanted to know fastest algorithm for finding nodes have only path from one node to other nodes.
[image]

these nodes are represented in string like this:

```
String path = "({A,B,C,D,E,F},{(A,C),(B,C),(C,E),(B,E),(B,D),(E,F)})";
```

Output should be like this:

```
output = {(A,C),(B,D),(E,F)}
```

I tried `split()` method but its an long procedure I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem

Comment: I assume you mean a single *simple* path? Because there is more than one path from B to D for example, B-C-E-B-D. This path is not simple

Comment: In your question you asked for `nodes` but your output is having `paths`???

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: from node a-c 1path but b-c two paths(b-c,b-e-c)

Comment: Really? You show the problem and ask for an answer? SO community wants to help not to solve your problems. What have you even tried?!

Comment: This question could better be asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/ Also you can use JGraphT library for graph related thing in Java.

Comment: i tried split() method but its an long procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to:

1. Find the cycles in your graph
2. Eliminate all edges that contribute to a cycle